# function doesn't continue to loop

Tags: loops, iteration, python-3.3

My function is acting a little bit weird.

```
def cow_latinify_sentence(sento):
''' Converting English to Cow Latin '''
    alpha = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
    finale = []
    worda = ""
    for word in sento.split():
        finale.append(word)
    for i in finale:
        if i[0].lower() in alpha:
            lista = list(i.lower())
            worda = worda.join(lista[1:] + [lista[0]]) + "oo"             
        else:
            return word + "moo"        
        return worda
```

When i run it with a sentence like:

```
cow_latinify_sentence("Cook me some eggs")
```

it returns: `ookcoo`. which is correct, however it doesn't loop around the other words in the sentence.

The function should perfectly return: `ookcoo emoo omesoo eggsmoo`

in addition to that, if i have a sentence like:

```
cow_latinify_sentence("aran likes his art")
```

it returns only the last element (`artmoo`) in the sentence being converted

so i'm guessing my issue is with the loops. i've tried changing positions of the return statement and got funny results as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you `return worda`, you return the first word and then the function stops executing. Thus, it won't return anything else.

In Python, I would suggest you use something called *list comprehension*. For details on how it works, please search Google. I will give you an example of how to apply that to your case here.

```
alpha = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
def cow_latinify_word(word):
    if word[0].lower() in alpha:
        lista = list(word.lower())
        return lista[1:] + [lista[0]] + "oo"
    else:
        return word + "moo"

def cow_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    words = sentence.split();
    return [ cow_latinify_word(word) for word in words]
```